# Looking to set up Media Signage

Tags: display, sensor, wireless

I'm Looking to set a multi screen system in my place of work. We will have roughly 6 monitors throughout our showroom displaying different adverts/price guides on rotation.

We have heard about using PI's for this but are looking for some answers to our worries.

1. is it possible to have 1 pi send upto 6 or more different displays to different monitors?
2. Can the content be changed remotely from other rooms from the same network?
3. Can you change the content through a server remotely even when you are not at the premises?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Ellis

Comment: 1. depends on number of monitors ... 2. yes ... 3. yes ... how are these answers useful to you?

Comment: 1. a pi 4 or 5 can only connect to 2 monitors ...